# Why does the value of exec-path differ based on how Emacs is launched?

Tags: linux, shell, path, emacs, zsh

I'm running Fedora 35 with Gnome 40. I have zsh set as my shell (I switched from bash to zsh using `useradd`). However, I see that the value of `exec-path` differs based on how I launch Emacs, vis using Gnome Activities and the Terminal, and I'd like to understand why. In particular, I notice that `/home/varunvats/.cargo/bin` is missing from the path when I launch Emacs from Gnome Activities.

Below is the result of executing `C-h` `v` `exec-path` on the different instances of Emacs.

### Gnome Activities

Emacs launched using `Super` followed by typing `Emacs` in the search box.

```
exec-path is a variable defined in 'C source code'.
Its value is
("/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/home/varunvats/bin" "/usr/libexec/emacs/27.2/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu")
```

### Terminal

Emacs launched by executing `emacs` in the Terminal app.

```
exec-path is a variable defined in 'C source code'.
Its value is
("/home/varunvats/.cargo/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/home/varunvats/bin" "/home/varunvats/bin" "/usr/libexec/emacs/27.2/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu")
```

### gtk-launch

I wanted to reproduce the Gnome Activities result by understanding how Gnome launches applications so that I could execute that command in my shell. [This resource](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal?newreg=2e580f2376e04f30af26e979a9972361) suggests that Gnome uses `gtk-launch` to launch applications, so I tried `gtk-launch emacs`. However, the value of `exec-path` in this instance is the same as what I get when I launch Emacs directly from the terminal.

```
exec-path is a variable defined in 'C source code'.
Its value is
("/home/varunvats/.cargo/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/home/varunvats/bin" "/home/varunvats/bin" "/usr/libexec/emacs/27.2/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu")
```

An additional difference between these instances is that `/home/varunvats/bin` appears twice when launched using the Terminal, either directly or using the `gtk-launch` command.

### Startup Files

I inspected my shell startup files to see if there was any difference between them that could explain this, but nothing stood out to me -- each of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, and `~/.zshenv` source `$HOME/.cargo/env`, which prefixes `$HOME/.cargo/bin` to `$PATH`:

```
% cat ~/.cargo/env 
#!/bin/sh
# rustup shell setup
# affix colons on either side of $PATH to simplify matching
case ":${PATH}:" in
    *:"$HOME/.cargo/bin":*)
        ;;
    *)
        # Prepending path in case a system-installed rustc needs to be overridden
        export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
        ;;
esac
```

I know I could use [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) to get `exec-path` to match my shell's `$PATH`, but I'd still like to understand how/why this difference comes about.

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate for [emacs.se] or [unix.se]

Comment: `~/.config/environment.d/` may also affect what you get.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `emacs-index-search` <kbd>RET</kbd> `exec-path` <kbd>RET</kbd> tells us:

> Whenever you specify a relative file name for an executable program
> (either in the CMD argument to one of the above commands, or in other
> contexts), Emacs searches for the program in the directories specified
> by the variable `exec-path`.  The value of this variable must be a list
> of directories; the default value is initialized from the environment
> variable `PATH` when Emacs is started (*note General Variables::).

Which answers your question -- Emacs is inheriting a different value
of `PATH` from the environment, depending on how or where you start it
from.  For instance, if you're manipulating `PATH` in your shell
config, only programs started via your shell will inherit that value.

(Whatever "Gnome Activities" is, it's not your shell, so naturally it's not parsing your shell config files.)